# How to apply tailwind styles only in a certain element?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm writing a WordPress plugin using ReactPress as well as Tailwind and don't want the part of my application's CSS that is written in React to affect the styles of the Wordpress part.

However, since

`index.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

is applied to the whole page, this screws up the rest of the page.

Is there any way to only make these styles apply inside a certain element, like this for example?

```css
div#root {
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure nesting or scoping tailwind styles to only a container with `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;` directly.

### Optimal Embedded / Nested Tailwind Configuration

You can alter the `tailwind.config.js` configuration and add a CSS Reset stylesheet to achieve an optimal "embedded" tailwind solution.

You can create a classic CSS Reset set of styles on a container where you want to cancel out the styles of the parent website or application. Where everything is prefixed with the container class you want to have styles reset on, so that the tailwind styles can be appropriately applied below this container.

Example CSS reset docs:

- https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- https://andy-bell.co.uk/a-modern-css-reset/

#### Example `embed-reset.css`

*partial example*

```css
.react-style-reset html,
.react-style-reset body,
.react-style-reset div,
.react-style-reset span,
.react-style-reset applet,
.react-style-reset object,
.react-style-reset iframe,
.react-style-reset h1,
.react-style-reset h2,
.react-style-reset h3,
.react-style-reset h4,
.react-style-reset h5,
.react-style-reset h6,
.react-style-reset p,
.react-style-reset blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

#### Example `tailwind.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  prefix: "tw-",
  important: true,
};
```

Notice:

- [Preflight is false](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight) - allows compatibility with other CSS in project - won't generate default baseline styles
- [Prefix is enabled](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) - avoid issues with existing css class names
- [Important is enabled](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important) - override any css that exists in the parent site / app

#### Example `main.tsx` React App

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./embed-reset.css";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("react-embed-1")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Notice the `embed-reset.css` comes before the `index.css`.

#### Parent Website / Application

You will need a `<div>` with the id `react-embed-1` and the class `react-style-reset` in your parent app for this example:

```html
<div id="react-embed-1" class="react-style-reset"></div>
```

Your parent app can load your react app's generated **.js bundle** and **.css file** on the page with the above div for the react app to appear with proper tailwind styles.

For example, if you are using vite + tailwind to generate these files, the build output index.html would include example tags for the script and stylesheet.

```html
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-7124ef29.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-8e021281.css">
```

Comment: It ended up being a problem completelely unrelated to this, but thank you anyways for the detailed answer!

Comment: No worries, I needed somewhere to document my answer and your question was still relevant to my issue lol. Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-scoped-preflight

This lets you define `isolationStrategy`, where you can pace a single selector or an array of selectors(inside your tailwind.config.js):

```
  plugins: [
    scopedPreflightStyles({
      isolationStrategy: isolateInsideOfContainer([".tw-class", "#tw-id"]),
    }),
  ],
```

This will apply it to all of the containers using the class `tw-class`, the `id tw-id` and its children.

A really smooth solution!